# Hyperledger Composer: Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am following a `hyperledger composer` [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html).

I am not able to execute step 15. while executing command :

```
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1-only -u admin -s adminpw -d alice
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and
>   return certificates. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with
>   error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]

When I checked the running containers, `CA` is not running.. If this is the case then i don't understand why there isn't a command to start CA in the `byfn` script.

Can anyone suggest a workaround to make the above command execute please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Composer Tutorial uses a modified version of `byfn.sh` which has a `-a` option to start the CA.

Be sure to clone the specific repo as follows:
`git clone -b issue-6978 https://github.com/sstone1/fabric-samples.git`

and then start byfn with the -a option: `./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can start fabric-ca manually by fabric-ca-server start -b admin:$ADMIN_PASSWORD command

Thanks
Kiran Thakkar

Answer (score 0):

I followed this suggestion and succeeded. Please try:
[Something wrong on deploy chaincode for hyperledger v1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427448/something-wrong-on-deploy-chaincode-for-hyperledger-v1-0/43449374)

Instruction: looking for the IP adress of your docker and replace to 'localhost' in all files: enrollAdmin.js, invoke.js...