# Error: No valid response from any peer (on running ./createpeerAdmincard.sh)

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am biginner in block chain development. I tried to hyperledger composer in multiple host. I successfully running ./startfabric.sh.
Then I tried to run ./createpeerAdmincard.sh
But I got an error message that no valid response from any peer. I changed many time composer vertion 0.16 to 0.19.x. And I tried to delete .composer file in home directory. But my problem is not solved. Please give a solution as possible.

Os is : Ubuntu 16.04
Hyperledger composer is:1.0.4

Thanks

Comment: Refer to this question: [Hyperledger Composer: Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918538/hyperledger-composer-error-failed-to-request-identity-error-trying-to-enroll)

Comment: There is not enough detail here to help - please edit your original question.  Please show versions currently being used (`composer -v`) and version of Fabric (`docker images`), and show exact complete commands used and exact complete errors.  Unless you specifically need an old version, you should use composer v0.20 and Fabric 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, I would run these commands in the directory which has ./startFabric.sh to uninstall previous versions of your CLI / remove all cards or credentials you may have generated up to this point.

`$ npm uninstall -g composer-rest-server
$ rm -rf ~/.composer
$ rm *.card
$ rm -rf credentials/`

(optional - kill docker containers)

`$ docker kill $(docker ps -q)
$ docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

now run

`./downloadFabric.sh`

and then after

`./startFabric.sh`

Now, install composer and composer-rest-server (version 19.5) ** this is very important.

`npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.5`

and then

`npm install -g composer-rest-server@0.19.5`

and then, after all that, try and use `./createPeerAdminCard.sh`

I find this tutorial pretty useful to get up and running with Composer -> https://github.com/IBM/BlockchainNetwork-CompositeJourney#1-starting-hyperledger-fabric

Comment: Hey Thank you for answering. I follow all you are provided. But error is same as Installing runtime for business network trade-network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Connect Failed
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Connect Failed
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Connect Failed

Comment: Please give another solution for this issue.

Comment: @salmanfaris which tutorial are you using for the trade-network? 

Also, what is the output of ```docker images``` and ```docker ps```? 

You should have hyperledger/fabric-ca, couchdb, orderer, peer at the minimum.

Comment: The output of docker images is
hyperledger/fabric-ca        x86_64-1.0.4        8e691b3509bf        10 months ago       238MB   
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   x86_64-1.0.4        cf24b91dfeb1        10 months ago       1.5GB   
hyperledger/fabric-orderer   x86_64-1.0.4        b17741e7b036        10 months ago       151MB   
hyperledger/fabric-peer      x86_64-1.0.4        1ce935adc397        10 months ago       154MB   
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv     x86_64-1.0.4        856061b1fed7        10 months ago       1.28GB

Comment: In running docker ps . I do not see CA. I do not know what is the reason for that.

Comment: Now i successfully start CA and all command is running successfully. Thank you for your help

Comment: Great. Did you figure out the problem? CA was not installed?