# Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ca

I am biginner in block chain development. I succesfully run ./startFabric.sh and ./createPeerAdminCard.sh .Then i succesfully run two command as follow below.

composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1-only -n trade-network
composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2-only -n trade-network

Then i tried to run

composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1-only -u admin -s adminpw -d alice

But i got error like the following

Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]

I tried many time to kill all process in docker and remove .composer file from home directory. But always showing the same error message.

Please help me as possible

Os: Ubuntu 16.04

Fabric vertion:1.0.4

Composer vertion:0.16.6

Thanks..

Comment: Refer to this question: [Hyperledger Composer: Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918538/hyperledger-composer-error-failed-to-request-identity-error-trying-to-enroll)

Comment: But my answer is not that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for error is Missing of Certificate Authorities(CA). I Just up my CA server. Now Working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This error "Failed to import the business network card Connection profile has no x-type property defined." means that a v0.20 client can't/won't import a card from an earlier version (probably v0.16).

I think maybe you are running the wrong version of `createPeerAdminCard.sh` script and it is trying to create and import an 'old' card.

With Composer v0.20 you need to get 'new' copies of the fabric-development-servers scripts which work with **Fabric 1.2**.

So I would suggest running the following:

1. run `teardownAllDocker.sh` script
2. remove the `fabric-dev-server` folder (might be `fabric-tools` if old)
3. remove the `~/.composer` folder
4. follow the [install doc](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) from Step 4 . - make sure to `export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv12` - this is what makes sure you get Fabric 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to help ...

The first 2 scripts you have run (./startFabric.sh and ./createPeerAdminCard.sh) are for a basic development Fabric.

The next 2 commands look like they are from the Multi-Org tutorial which uses a different Fabric and has different cards and crypto material.

Unless there is a particular reason for using an old version of Composer, I would suggest using Composer v0.20, which requires Fabric 1.2.

If you are a beginner I would suggest working with the [Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) to start with.

Comment: But i face vertion issue when i changed composer vertion from .16.6 to .20

Comment: The error is:Failed to import the business network card
Connection profile has no `x-type` property defined. It is not valid for this version of composer

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a default file (e.g. connection.json, env.json, etc.) to hold your base connnection profile, simply change the "type" term in that default file to "x-type"

In converting from v0.16 to v0.20, you must first remove the v0.16 composer tools from your system, then install the v0.20 version.

To remove v0.16.6:

```
npm uninstall -g composer-cli
npm uninstall -g generator-hyperledger-composer
npm uninstall -g composer-rest-server
```

To install V0.20.2:

```
npm install -g --python=python2.7 composer-cli@0.20.2
npm install -g --python=python2.7 generator-hyperledger-composer@0.20.2
npm install -g --python=python2.7 composer-rest-server@0.20.2
npm install -g --python=python2.7 yo
```

If you're running nodejs, then you also have to update both package.json files (network/package/json as well as your {base folder}package.json) from 0.16.x to ^0.20.2