# Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to run the Hyperledger fabric Tuna app and getting the below error when running the `regiseterAdmin.js`

```
  Store path:/home/chaindev/.hfc-key-store
Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/chaindev/fabricProjects/src/github.com/education/LFS171x/fabric-material/tuna-app/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClientImpl.js:711:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
Failed to enroll admin: Error: Failed to enroll admin
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue was occurring for me because I had the wrong Private Key name mentioned in the `docker-compose.yml` file 
`FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/4239aa0dcd76daeeb8ba0cda701851d14504d31aad1b2ddddbac6a57365e497c_sk`

When I re-generated the artificats the key file name was changed and after correction everything worked fine. 

Also thanks for rocket-fabric group for mentioning the commands on how to look for logs in docker container. Below commands can be useful to debug

```
docker ps -a 

docker logs <ca container name>
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs need be updated on this. Localhost 127.0.0.1 does not work for Docker For Windows and Docker Toolbox as they both give their run-time IP address on start of Docker (here taken as 192.168.1.2). 
This start-up IP needs to be updated in the registerAdmin.js file (or in my case enrollAdmin.js file as referred in the Tutorial "[Writing First App](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html)" ).
The enrollAdmin.js needs be updated in this line:

```
// be sure to change the http to https when the CA is running TLS enabled
    fabric_ca_client = new Fabric_CA_Client('http://192.168.1.2:7054', tlsOptions , 'ca.example.com', crypto_suite);
```

The output certificate should be like:

> Successfully enrolled admin user "admin"

> Assigned the admin user to the fabric client :: "name":"admin","mspid":"Org1MSP","roles":null,"affiliation":"","enrollmentSecret":"","enrollment": "signingIdentity":"c198861140fc723abc058c70d23395a2d7b73c926ca673b53d713053aaade419","identity":{"certificate":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICATCCAaigAwIBAgIUK/o2ege+nT73jK/NXSgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw\nczELM...QnCkD6AiApKxxU1maQIt1TKFl3KYZWGBNDSSa6SCbob7q1p5xfpQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"}}}

Similar problem [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427448/something-wrong-on-deploy-chaincode-for-hyperledger-v1-0?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 1):

As your **.hfc-key-store** directory is in **chaindev**,

Try running the following commands:

**$ cd ~/chaindev/**
**$ rm -rf .hfc-key-store/**

Then, run the command:

**$ node registerAdmin.js**

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if the port in PeerAdmin@Org.card does not match the port in docker-compose.yaml, I had hard time finding solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mismatch in connection protocols, either you have done fabric setup without TLS and trying to connect to CA using https protocol or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

`Run docker ps` and check if all the docker containers are running or not.

If it is not running run it, if it fail, download the fabric binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
I run `networkDown.sh` and the run `startFabric.sh` again.Then it succeeded.